# Monitor Number of S3 Buckets in account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

There is a limit of 100 buckets per AWS account. My application is creating buckets when certain conditions are met. Is there a mechanism to monitor the number of buckets created in my account? I would like to alarm/get notified before I reach the 100 bucket limit.

**Edit:** The plan is to create prefix per customer and grant access to the prefix using Resource Policy. The customers would be uploading objects to only the prefix they have access to. We would update resource policy every time we create a new prefix. Sample policy as shown below. Once we hit limit on Resource Policy size for bucket, we would then need to create new bucket.

```
"Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS":"123456789012"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::TestBucketName/123456789012/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::TestBucketName/123456789012"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Check `Service Quota`. You may be able to create an alarm based off of that.

Comment: Are these metrics that are emitted periodically? I could find only API calls to check the quota limits.

Comment: Just checked. There is no metric to monitor number of S3 buckets. You will have to create a lambda function, execute it periodically using CloueWatch Events to check the number of buckets and take the appropriate action.

Comment: Are you aware that 100 buckets is a soft limit that you can just ask to be increased?

Comment: If possible, avoid situations that create "One bucket per...", such as one bucket per customer. It's fine to use dozens or even hundreds of buckets, but avoid situations that would require _thousands_ of buckets.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein    Yeah. Avoiding create "per customer" but we would need to grant access to multiple customers. The customers would have access only to a prefix in the bucket (i.e. one S3 prefix per customer) which we plan to achieve by using Resource policy. However, there being a 20k Resource policy size limit, we would need to create buckets after a certain threshold.

Comment: How are you granting access to your "customers"? How are they accessing S3? Are you giving them IAM credentials -- are they permanent or temporary credentials? Can you tell us more about your application and what users do with it? (Feel free to add details to your Question.)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Included some additional details to the question

Comment: How do you intend authenticating customers and providing them access? You would not typically give them IAM User credentials, since these are intended for use _within_ your organization. How are the users interacting with AWS -- web page? CLI? Program? Cyberduck?

Comment: They would be using standard S3 cli or API. We would like to avoid having customers make multiple calls to upload single object

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for S3 there is no AWS backed solution that performs all of the actions for monitoring S3.

To do this you would need to create your own solution, the below is a suggestion for covering this problem:

- Use a Lambda function to call the [list-buckets](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/list-buckets.html) function, counting the total number of buckets in your account. Push the value to CloudWatch as a custom metric.
- Create a CloudWatch alarm for this metric based on a specific threshold.
- Create a Lambda function and use the [list-service-quotas](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/service-quotas/list-service-quotas.html) function to get your service quotas for S3 buckets. Use this to update the alarm thresholds.
- Set both of these Lambda functions on a [scheduled CloudWatch event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html).

For other services quotas you might be able to take advantage of the [Trusted Advisor API](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/support/describe-trusted-advisor-checks.html) if you are using Business or Enterprise support plan, however this only covers specific quotas for services.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is running on node.js, you can get the number of buckets using the following code:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
s3.listBuckets({}, (err, data) => {
   if (err) console.log(err);
   else     console.log(data.Buckets.length); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that:

- You are providing customers with credentials associated with an **IAM User** (not a good practice because generally IAM User credentials are for your internal staff, not external entities)
- You want to allow customers to upload data to Amazon S3

I would recommend:

- Use **one Amazon S3 bucket**
- Allow customers to **access their own folder** (Prefix) within the bucket
- This can be done by creating a bucket policy that uses **IAM Policy Variables**, which can automatically insert the username into the policy. This allows one policy to apply differently for every user.

Here is an example from [IAM policy elements: Variables and tags - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html):

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"],
      "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["${aws:username}/*"]}}
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/${aws:username}/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

This way, users can access their own folder, but cannot access other users' folders.

Comment: The users being referred above would be IAM users, correct? So in a single customer account, if there are multiple IAM Users, each IAM user would get a separate prefix. Is my understanding correct? If I apply the above policy, how can I control which customer accounts can upload data to my bucket? If I understand the policy correctly, any IAM user in any account would be able to upload data into my bucket, if they know the name for the bucket.  The customers are separate AWS accounts and **not** different IAM users in same account

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you wish to control it more finely, then you would need to add a policy to each IAM User individually, which grants them access to the specific bucket/folder. These policies would be _instead_ of the bucket policy.